# Can we add new users and permissions to keycloak without using the admin console?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api, keycloak-connect, keycloak-gatekeeper

So I have multiple services running in the cluster. Is there a way to send new users or new permissions coming from new/updated services in the cluster without interacting with the admin console? I know Keycloak has rest APIs but will I need to have a service registry/discovery to send new data to keycloak?

Comment: You need to describe a specific example and scenario for a service. Keycloak provides a role based the resource access control. It can be variety to fine control. I can't figure out what is your looking for what feature.

Comment: You can configure keycloak to use a provider and for example connect it via LDAP protocol to an active directory. This way you can decouple the management of users from keycloak and you can set the way how or how often they are synced.